# Explorer is slow to open new window on Windows 10: what could the issue be?

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, unresponsive

I have an MSI laptop with a freshly installed Windows 10.

Explorer takes about 5 seconds to open a new window. What could the issue be?

Demo: https://youtu.be/o05SOF1k_8o

[image: E]

Comment: freshly installed Windows 10   ......    Should be faster than 5 seconds.  Things to consider:   (1) Windows fully updated including optional updates  (2) available memory  (3) speed of hard drive.   (4) Is there software installed that is not fully compatible?

Comment: @John thanks, indeed there are a few windows update. RAM is 64GB. 2 NVMe SSDs mounted as RAID 0. The laptop does come with some MSI crapware. Full laptop specs: https://us-store.msi.com/GS76-Stealth-11UH-078?search=%2011UH-078 tldr should be fast

Comment: Seems strange.  I tested my Windows 10 VM and Explorer opens in 1 second - 2 at the most.

Comment: @John yep, same in my Windows 10 in my VM (ironically, VM hosted by the same laptop where windows 10 without VM is slow): indeed between 1 and 2 seconds there (which btw is still ridiculously slow). No idea why 5 seconds on this laptop.

Comment: PS: low recording quality because of https://superuser.com/q/1734336/116475 + https://superuser.com/q/1734388/116475

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to attach Images in your WebBrowser (on SuperUser StackExchange) and hence opening the Windows Dialog.

It may be some slowness in your WebBrowser. Try with alternate WebBrowser. Or even opening other Documents with notepad & MSPaint & Such, through this Windows Dialog.
If it is fast or normal, WebBrowser may be the culprit.

If it is still slow, Windows ( Caching / Icons / Prefetch / Background Updates / Virus Checking / Etc ) or Hardware ( Processor / Disk / Memory / FIleSystem / Caching / Etc ) may be the culprit.

In Case it is Windows Updates over Network or Windows generating the Internal Caches : Issue should Disappear (when all background tasks are over) in a Day or two.

In Case Issue Persists : Check your Processor Usage / Network Usage / HardDisk Usage / Memory Usage (eg in task manager) when opening the Windows Dialog to get more Data about your Issue.

Comment: Thanks, same pb with any web browser. I checked Processor Usage / Network Usage / HardDisk Usage / Memory Usage (eg in task manager) when opening the Windows Dialog to get more Data but didn't spot any pb. After rebooting Windows, Explorer is much faster: it takes less than 1 second to open a new window. But I still don't understand the reason for it.

Comment: "In Case it is Windows Updates over Network or Windows generating the Internal Caches : Issue should Disappear **(when all background tasks are over)** in a Day or two." I guess these tasks got over and Windows Explorer is quick ! [[ Windows will execute all sorts of stuff in the background , including Cache , Prefetch , Checking Latest Updates , Malware Scan , Windows Defender , Connecting to Store , Etc ; Issue might Disappear when all this is DONE ! ]]

Comment: Thanks, the slowness did stay present for over 1 week, until I finally rebooted the PC.

Answer (score -1):

After rebooting Windows, Explorer is much faster: it takes less than 1 second to open a new window as shown below.

[image]

While I still don't understand the reason for it, it provides a temporary fix.