# ShareX doesn't save the cursor in the gif recordings, what could the issue be?

Tags: windows-10, cursor, animated-gif, sharex

I configured ShareX so that it saves the cursor in gif recordings, but it doesn't save the cursor in gif recordings. What could the issue be?

[image]

E.g. in the following, I click on `Ask` but ShareX didn't save the cursor in the gif recording:

[image]

I use ShareX 14.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: This might be a known bug, where the cursor is not missing, just misplaced. To test if this is your problem, set in *settings > System > Display* the value of "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100%.

Comment: @harrymc thanks very much, you're right. Can you please post your comment as an answer? I can do if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor in ShareX is only misplaced. The program does not correctly
handle the case of high-resolution monitors when the resolution
is magnified for readability.

To avoid this problem, you must set the resolution to 100% :

Run *Settings > System > Display* and set the value of
"Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100%.

Now the cursor will be in its right place inside the recording.