# Camtasia doesn't save the cursor in the GIF recordings, what could the issue be?

Tags: windows-10, cursor, screen-recorder, camtasia

I use TechSmith Camtasia 2022 on Windows 10 and it doesn't save the cursor in the GIF recordings. What could the issue be?

Camtasia is configured as follows:

[image]

[image]

Adding cursor effects in Camtasia Studio afterwards does work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Run Settings` -> `System` -> `Display` -> `Change the size of text, apps, and other items` must be set to 100%. Thanks [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for the [tip](https://superuser.com/a/1734700/116475) on another program with the same issue.